# 411 Length Required .Net Core Api hosted on IIS and ESP8266

Tags: .net-core, arduino, esp8266

I'm building .net core Api for my ESP8266 sensors.
Sensors sending update in JSON.
I'm getting 411 HTTP Error, but Content-Length is provided in request.

I think problem is in multiple Hypertext Transfer Protocol - see in wireshark screenshot - but how to solve this?

Api [SourceCode](https://github.com/pkozak2/Esp8266VueMeteoStation/blob/master/ApiAndWeb/Esp8266VueMeteo/Controllers/SensorUpdateController.cs)

ESP8266 HTTP library adding Content-Length header here: [SourceCode #L673](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/372a3ec297dfe8501bed1ec4552244695b5e8ced/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/src/ESP8266HTTPClient.cpp#L673)

Request in Wireshark:
[image: Wireshark screenshot]

Comment: you added extra CRLF(\r\n) after Authorization field. there should be single pair of them ( \r\n ). When you use some library you should not add CRLF yourself - library does this for you

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thank you!